# SQL - Add multiple columns to a VIEW

Tags: sql, join, left-join, sql-view

There is a View that I created, and works fine (shown in View "A" below). 
Now I have to join columns from another Table to the view. My work is shown in View "B" below. 
Does anyone know what the correct syntax is?

(Join to LK_METRICS using METRIC_NUMBER = METRIC_ID_OLD
Add [small title], [title], [demonstration], and [SLS] columns from metric tablesmall)

VIEW **A**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_PS_DA]
AS  WITH
today AS
(   SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS 
    WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
SELECT 
  p.*,
  hrs.DATE_ORDINAL      ENTER_HRSC_ORDINAL,
  strt.DATE_ORDINAL     START_DATE_ORDINAL,
  ndt.DATE_ORDINAL      END_DATE_ORDINAL,
  today.DATE_ORDINAL    TODAY_ORDINAL,
FROM dbo.PS_DA p
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS hrs
  ON p.ENTER_HRSC = hrs.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS strt
  ON p.START_DATE = strt.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS ndt
  ON p.END_DATE = ndt.[DATE]
CROSS JOIN today;  
GO
```

VIEW **B**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_PS_DA]
AS WITH
today AS
(   SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS -- This contains the date data needed
    WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
SELECT 
  p.*,
  hrs.DATE_ORDINAL      ENTER_HRSC_ORDINAL,
  strt.DATE_ORDINAL     START_DATE_ORDINAL,
  ndt.DATE_ORDINAL      END_DATE_ORDINAL,
  today.DATE_ORDINAL    TODAY_ORDINAL,
  kst.[Small Title] Small_Title,
  kt.[Title]    Title,
  kd.[Demonstration]  Demonstration,
  ks.SLS    SLS

FROM dbo.PS_DA p, dbo.LK_METRICS k
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS hrs
  ON p.ENTER_HRSC = hrs.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS strt
  ON p.START_DATE = strt.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS ndt
  ON p.END_DATE = ndt.[DATE]
CROSS JOIN today,
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_METRICS k
  ON k.METRIC_ID_OLD = METRIC_NUMBER
```

Comment: Did you get an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. You just have a little extra happening in there. Take out the bit after the comma on your `FROM ..` line:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_PS_DA]
AS WITH
today AS
(   SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS -- This contains the date data needed
    WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
SELECT 
  p.*,
  hrs.DATE_ORDINAL      ENTER_HRSC_ORDINAL,
  strt.DATE_ORDINAL     START_DATE_ORDINAL,
  ndt.DATE_ORDINAL      END_DATE_ORDINAL,
  today.DATE_ORDINAL    TODAY_ORDINAL,
  kst.[Small Title] Small_Title,
  kt.[Title]    Title,
  kd.[Demonstration]  Demonstration,
  ks.SLS    SLS

FROM dbo.PS_DA p
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS hrs
  ON p.ENTER_HRSC = hrs.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS strt
  ON p.START_DATE = strt.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS ndt
  ON p.END_DATE = ndt.[DATE]
CROSS JOIN today,
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_METRICS k
  ON k.METRIC_ID_OLD = METRIC_NUMBER
```

The only other thing is specifying which table `METRIC_NUMBER` is from. IS that `p.METRIC_NUMBER`? Chances are it won't make a difference overall since you probably only have a single table with the field `METRIC_NUMBER` but with SQL it's a good idea to be as explicit as possible.

Lastly, you can then use fields from your `K` table in your SELECT statement like:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_PS_DA]
AS WITH
today AS
(   SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS -- This contains the date data needed
    WHERE [DATE] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
SELECT 
  p.*,
  k.somefield,
  k.someotherfield,
  hrs.DATE_ORDINAL      ENTER_HRSC_ORDINAL,
  strt.DATE_ORDINAL     START_DATE_ORDINAL,
  ndt.DATE_ORDINAL      END_DATE_ORDINAL,
  today.DATE_ORDINAL    TODAY_ORDINAL,
  kst.[Small Title] Small_Title,
  kt.[Title]    Title,
  kd.[Demonstration]  Demonstration,
  ks.SLS    SLS

FROM dbo.PS_DA p
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS hrs
  ON p.ENTER_HRSC = hrs.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS strt
  ON p.START_DATE = strt.[DATE]
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_NET_WORK_DAYS ndt
  ON p.END_DATE = ndt.[DATE]
CROSS JOIN today,
LEFT JOIN dbo.LK_METRICS k
  ON k.METRIC_ID_OLD = METRIC_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill. I ran the script and it worked. I used the fields from 'k' in the SELECT Statement - made my life easier. It does look like SQL requires explicity. Perhaps I was going overboard with that in my first attempt. I appreciate your help

Comment: If it's picky about it being the table being explicitly stated, that's most likely because the column `METRIC_NUMBER` occurs in more than one table joined in your statement, so the DB doesn't know which `METRIC_NUMBER` you're talking about. Glad to hear it's working!

Comment: In that case I can specify that as p.METRIC_NUMBER versus k.METRIC_ID. It shouldn't be necessary since ID and Number are different. However, that will clarify is as much as possible. Thank you